# Winform - SetFocus to textbox inside usercontrol on TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, focus

Winform application
Multiple tabs
on the tabs are replicated Usercontrol

When clicking on a particular tab, I would like to setfocus to a textbox within the usercontrol.  I would like to this if possible from within the tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged event.

ex:

textbox name = txtOne
txtOne resides within UserControlA
UserControlA resides within tabControl.SelectedTab.Text = "Tab2"

When I click Tab2 I'd like Focus to be set to txtone.

I've tried: (and many other things!)
UserControlA.Controls["txtone"].SelectAll();  - returns object reference not set to an instance of an object

Thanks!

Comment: If possible share some code.

Comment: Is `txtone` an immediate child of UserControlA, or is it within another control (e.g. a GroupBox, a Panel, etc.)?

Comment: txtOne is inside of a GroupBox frame

Comment: GroupBox name is fameFD

Comment: Add a public FirstControl property to the user Control.  Return txtOne.  Now you can't get it wrong anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `txtone` is not an immediate child of `UserControlA`, `UserControlA.Controls["txtone"]` will return null.

You can either dig your way down the control hierarchy with control names (`UserControlA.Controls["fameFD"].Controls["txtone"]`) or simply expose `txtone` as a public field or property in your UserControl class.  The latter would look something like this:

```
public TextBox TxtOne {
    get
    {
        return txtone;
    }
}
```

Then you could refer to the textbox from external code like this:

```
UserControlA.TxtOne.SelectAll();
```

Comment: OK Thanks!  Let me try the property method.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks!  I'm new on here - how do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: Looks like you found it ;)